# VB.NET OleDB MSAccess GetOleDBSchema returns incorrect number of Queries (Procedures)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, ms-access-2007, oledb

I have a perplexing problem that I have been grappling with for many hours to no avail.

Our (general audience) application compares queries in the latest version of our MS-Access database with end-users currently installed versions and and updates/syncs. the DB accordingly. Although this functionality has been working, it is now broken. I have resorted to the simplest test to demonstrate the behavior. OLEDB is NOT returning the correct number of queries.

After opening the Access 2007 database, I display the location and correct number of queries:

```
?CurrentDB.Name
C:\Users\Ron\Documents\Database4.accdb
?CurrentDB.QueryDefs.Count
1
```

The following simple form calls the OleDbSchemaTable method, but returns the wrong number of rows / queries (=0):

```
Public Class Form1
    Private ConnStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Ron\Documents\Database4.accdb"

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim dbo As DataTable = GetSchemaInfo()
        Debug.Print("Number of queries=" & dbo.Rows.Count)
    End Sub
    Private Function GetSchemaInfo()
        Try
            Dim db As DataTable
            Using conn = New OleDb.OleDbConnection(ConnStr)
                conn.Open()
                db = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(System.Data.OleDb.OleDbSchemaGuid.Procedures, Nothing)
            End Using
            Return db

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            Return Nothing
        End Try
    End Function
End Class
```

**Immediate Window**:
    Number of queries=0

I have tried everything I can think of (Compact/Repair, running on a different machine). Unfortunately, I have only one copy of Access 2007 to test with. Could this be a virus?

Any and all ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 types of saved queries.

1. Simple `SELECT` queries which could be created with `CREATE VIEW` DDL statements.
2. All other queries.  These can not be created with `CREATE VIEW` but could be with `CREATE PROCEDURE`.  Included within this category are: "action queries" (insert, update, delete, "make table"); parameter queries; simple `SELECT` queries which include an `ORDER BY` clause; and perhaps more I can't recall at the moment.

Schema views include the first type.  Schema procedures include the second type.  `QueryDefs.Count` gives you the count of all saved queries, which includes both types.

Try the VBA procedure below in your database.  With my database, I get this output in the Immediate window:

```
QueryDefs.Count: 66
Views: 34
Procedures: 32
```

Unfortunately I don't know how to translate this VBA to Dot.Net.  Perhaps that doesn't matter.  I just want to emphasize that `QueryDefs.Count` should be the count of views plus the count of procedures.  And it looks to me like your code asks for procedures only.

```
Public Sub CountQueries()
    Const adSchemaProcedures = 16
    Const adSchemaViews = 23
    Dim cn As Object
    Dim rs As Object
    Dim i As Long

    Debug.Print "QueryDefs.Count: " & CurrentDb.QueryDefs.Count

    Set cn = CurrentProject.Connection
    Set rs = cn.OpenSchema(adSchemaViews)
    i = 0
    With rs
        Do While Not .EOF
            i = i + 1
            'Debug.Print !TABLE_NAME '
            .MoveNext
        Loop
        .Close
    End With
    Debug.Print "Views: " & CStr(i)

    Set rs = cn.OpenSchema(adSchemaProcedures)
    i = 0
    With rs
        Do While Not .EOF
            i = i + 1
            'Debug.Print !PROCEDURE_NAME '
            .MoveNext
        Loop
        .Close
    End With
    Debug.Print "Procedures: " & CStr(i)

    Set rs = Nothing
    Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much (both HansUp and Remou). I have no clue why using "Procedure" worked previously for both Action and Select queries in VB.NET OLEDB.

Comment: I'm not clear about that either, Ron.  If the previous `SELECT` queries included `ORDER BY` clauses, they would be procedures rather than view from the schema perspective.

Comment: That sounds logical. So long as it is one (VIEW) or the other (PROCEDURE) I can finally resolve this. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of schemas for MS Access, schema views and schema procedures. Procedures are action queries, views are select queries. So you need

```
   OleDbSchemaGuid.Views
```

Note that the OleDbSchemaGuid returns the wrong data type for memo fields.